# Official doc of ALL cleanup steps after fork before exec

Tags: unix, exec, fork, sigprocmask

On Unix, I'm aware that after calling fork(), I need to reset my signal mask and close file descriptors that I don't want the child to have, before calling exec().

But, what else might I need to do?

Is there a comprehensive doc somewhere that lists all the things that you might want to clean up when forking a child process in order to give it a nice standard execution environment?

I'm currently on Linux, but I'd like a document that includes details for other Unixes as well, possibly with ways to autoconf-test for them.

Answer (score 0):

`fork(3)` provides a [comprehensive list](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork). It's a bit long to quote here but as per SO policy I'll do so anyway:

> The fork() function shall create a new process. The new process (child
>   process) shall be an exact copy of the calling process (parent
>   process) except as detailed below:
>
> - The child process shall have a unique process ID.
> - The child process ID also shall not match any active process group ID.
> - The child process shall have a different parent process ID, which shall be the process ID of the calling process.
> - The child process shall have its own copy of the parent's file descriptors. Each of the child's file descriptors shall refer to the
>     same open file description with the corresponding file descriptor of
>     the parent.
> - The child process shall have its own copy of the parent's open directory streams. Each open directory stream in the child process may
>     share directory stream positioning with the corresponding directory
>     stream of the parent.
> - The child process shall have its own copy of the parent's message catalog descriptors.
> - The child process' values of tms_utime, tms_stime, tms_cutime, and tms_cstime shall be set to 0.
> - The time left until an alarm clock signal shall be reset to zero, and the alarm, if any, shall be canceled; see alarm().
> - All semadj values shall be cleared.
> - File locks set by the parent process shall not be inherited by the child process.
> - The set of signals pending for the child process shall be initialized to the empty set.
> - Interval timers shall be reset in the child process.
> - Any semaphores that are open in the parent process shall also be open in the child process.
> - The child process shall not inherit any address space memory locks established by the parent process via calls to mlockall() or mlock().
> - Memory mappings created in the parent shall be retained in the child process. MAP_PRIVATE mappings inherited from the parent shall also be
>     MAP_PRIVATE mappings in the child, and any modifications to the data
>     in these mappings made by the parent prior to calling fork() shall be
>     visible to the child. Any modifications to the data in MAP_PRIVATE
>     mappings made by the parent after fork() returns shall be visible only
>     to the parent. Modifications to the data in MAP_PRIVATE mappings made
>     by the child shall be visible only to the child.
> - For the SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR scheduling policies, the child process shall inherit the policy and priority settings of the parent
>     process during a fork() function. For other scheduling policies, the
>     policy and priority settings on fork() are implementation-defined.
> - Per-process timers created by the parent shall not be inherited by the child process.
> - The child process shall have its own copy of the message queue descriptors of the parent. Each of the message descriptors of the
>     child shall refer to the same open message queue description as the
>     corresponding message descriptor of the parent.
> - No asynchronous input or asynchronous output operations shall be inherited by the child process.
> - A process shall be created with a single thread. If a multi-threaded process calls fork(), the new process shall contain a replica of the
>     calling thread and its entire address space, possibly including the
>     states of mutexes and other resources. Consequently, to avoid errors,
>     the child process may only execute async-signal-safe operations until
>     such time as one of the exec functions is called. Fork handlers may be
>     established by means of the pthread_atfork() function in order to
>     maintain application invariants across fork() calls. When the
>     application calls fork() from a signal handler and any of the fork
>     handlers registered by pthread_atfork() calls a function that is not
>     asynch-signal-safe, the behavior is undefined.
> - If the Trace option and the Trace Inherit option are both supported: If the calling process was being traced in a trace stream that had its
>     inheritance policy set to POSIX_TRACE_INHERITED, the child process
>     shall be traced into that trace stream, and the child process shall
>     inherit the parent's mapping of trace event names to trace event type
>     identifiers. If the trace stream in which the calling process was
>     being traced had its inheritance policy set to
>     POSIX_TRACE_CLOSE_FOR_CHILD, the child process shall not be traced
>     into that trace stream. The inheritance policy is set by a call to the
>     posix_trace_attr_setinherited() function.
> - If the Trace option is supported, but the Trace Inherit option is not supported: The child process shall not be traced into any of the
>     trace streams of its parent process.
> - If the Trace option is supported, the child process of a trace controller process shall not control the trace streams controlled by
>     its parent process.
> - The initial value of the CPU-time clock of the child process shall be set to zero.
> - The initial value of the CPU-time clock of the single thread of the child process shall be set to zero. All other process characteristics
>     defined by IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 shall be the same in the parent and
>     child processes. The inheritance of process characteristics not
>     defined by IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 is unspecified by IEEE Std
>     1003.1-2001.

Comment: This describes everything that I **don't** have to worry about.  For example, it doesn't say anything about the signal mask, because the signal mask is something you need to clean up yourself.

I'm looking for the list of things neither fork() nor exec() take care of for you.

Comment: Hmm, you're partly right. It does mention file descriptors, directory streams and message queue descriptors as potential things to worry about though.